# Time stamp in influxDB v3 client

Tags: node.js, influxdb-2, influxql, influx-line-protocol

I made a influxdb v3 client using node.js and giving line:
line=`emp,name=Rakesh age=28.0,weight=44.0`
this line got saved with timestamp 1700633869044.8845
now if I want to update the age I'm running this line
line=`emp,name=Rakesh age=28.0,weight=44.0 1700633869044.8845`

but await client.write(line, database) giving me this error
statusCode: 400,
statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
body: `{"code":"invalid","message":"failed to parse line protocol: errors encountered on line(s):\\nerror parsing line 1 (1-based): Could not parse entire line. Found trailing content: '.8845'","line":1}`,
contentType: undefined

I think it's because the timestamp is in floating point.
Please help me with it

Comment: Yes, timestamp cannot be floating point. If you want to write with ns precision, you need to multiply your timestamp in ms by 1000000, ie. send 1700633869044884500. Default WriteOptions precision is ns, so you should be good to go.